# Is there any reason why programmers use a char with System.in.read()?

Tags: java, escaping, system.in

I notice that the following line of code exists a lot.  (For example on this website.)

```
char ch = (char) System.in.read();  // uses a char, and requires a cast.
```

Now to test for a particular character keystroke, or an ASCII value, or an escape sequence, etc..

```
if (ch == 'a' || ch == 65 || ch == '\n' || ch == 13) System.out.print("true");
```

Does using a char above provide any benefits over the following line of code below, which uses an int?

```
int i = System.in.read();  // uses an int, which requires no cast.
```

The int variable "i" can be used in the same if statement as previously shown, above.

Comment: Honestly, the answer is probably as simple as readability. The intention is to use it as a char, so programmers cast it to a char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither approach is correct. The correct way to read characters from `System.in` is to use an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) (or a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) if that provides the right functionality). The reason is that `InputStream.read()` reads a single byte, not characters, and some characters require reading more than one byte. You can also specify the character encoding to be used when converting bytes to characters.

```
Reader rdr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
int i = rdr.next();
if (i == -1) {
    // end of input
} else {
    // normal processing; safe to cast i to char if convenient
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first line in your sample code: `Reader rdr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);`

Please can you explain why the variable "rdr" is of type Reader, and not of type InputStreamReader?  Specifically, please can you explain the benefit that this provides.  Thanks a lot.

Also, in your code sample, when you used the method next(), did you mean read()?

Comment: @user2911290 - No particular benefit in this case. It's just habit; I usually program to an interface unless I need the specific functionality of a more concrete type. It makes future evolution of the code easier. (For instance, I could switch to a `CharArrayReader` or a `PipedReader` without worrying about whether there were dependencies on methods or behavior specific `InputStreamReader`.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for the cast at all.  This is fine

```
int i = System.in.read();
if(i == 'a'){
   // do something
}
```

You can do this, because `'a'` is a value within the range of an int.

Also, be aware that doing the cast directly to a char *may* be problematic when reading files and such, because what `InputStream.read()` does is read a `byte` not a `char`.  A `char` is two bytes wide.